# Disable the future date selection in datepicker

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker

This is my date picker dialog code. I want to disable the future date selection in my date picker dialog box.

Can anybody suggest how?

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(id)
    {
        case 1:
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            Toast.makeText(DateActivity.this, "- onCreateDialog -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date = "Year: " + String.valueOf(year) + "\n"
                    + "Month: " + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + "\n"
                    + "Day: " + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);

        Toast.makeText(DateActivity.this, date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an `OnDateChangedListener` to your `DateTimePicker`, where in

```
onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

check if the date is in your allowed range and if not, call `view.updateDate` with your maximum allowed date.

Answer (score 1):

Put on this method inside on onCreateDialog, solved this problem for future date must be not selection on date picker dailog,

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, intYear, intMonth, intDay);
        mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Important as Future date not selection
        return mDatePickerDialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yourdatepicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: This is really just a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020729//22317275#22317275).